# Revoking a GitHub personal access token in the Git CLI

Tags: git, github

I creaed a GitHub personal access token for use with the Git CLI.  Generating and setting it up worked great, but I gave the token the wrong permissions.  Now I can't change the access token on the client.  Whenever I try to do something, it just says:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The repository *does* exist and the upstream is set correctly.  I have cleared all of the Git configurations like `user.name` and `user.email`.  I have revoked the access token on GitHub.  What else is there for me to do?!  How would I do something like change accounts?

Comment: It looks like it's using your SSH keys, not your username+token. What protocol is the remote configured to use?

Comment: They're using git@github.com:username/repo.git for fetch and push.

Comment: If you want to use a personal access token you will need to update your remote to use HTTPS. See also: [authenticating to GitHub from Git using HTTPS](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/#cloning-with-https-urls-recommended).

Comment: You're a miracle worker.  Can you submit that as an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: No worries, feel free to answer your own question with the detailed steps about how to generate the correct token and add the remote with the correct protocol.

Comment: Actually, I don't think that's the solution - oops.  Yes, that does fix the problem, but I remember now that I used the git@ protocol instead of HTTPS or SSH because using HTTPS made it repeatedly prompt me for my username and password.  SSH has the same problem with my public key.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/5343068/1267663